# Edit and Continue is not working in VS2010

Tags: c#, debugging

for some reason this no longer works. I ugraded the winforms solution from VS2008 to VS2010 and on new machine also Windows 7 64bit but id does not allow edit and continue

I haver set the options to enable it and to compile against 86 cpu

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> also Windows 7 64bit

Edit+Continue only works for 32-bit code.  Easy fix, and the default now for VS2010 projects: Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target = x86.  You can of course leave that setting for your Release configuration at Any CPU.

Comment: I'm going to go out on the limb and say that this is because VS2010 (like 08, 05, 03, and 02) are all 32-bit applications running in a WOW64 sandbox.  But, it is true, you can only edit and continue a 32-bit application (and IFF the method you are editing does not include lambda expressions).

Comment: I've tried all of that. Read the articles.set all the options. Still does not work. I've got no lamda in the code. all set to x86. I am starting to think that it is the 64 bit causing the problem

Comment: @kurasa I have the same problem, changing the platform target won't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795795/cant-edit-and-continue-when-using-visual-studio-2010-on-a-64-bit-machine-app-ta). quoting from it

1. Edit and Continue is enabled under Tools>Options>Debugging>Edit and Continue
2. My solution platform is set to x86
3. My solution configuration is set to Debug
4. All my projects are building for Debug and x86
5. For all projects under Projects>Properties>Build the Optimize code is unchecked
6. tools->options->unselect intellitrace events and call information

Answer (score 1):

*I know it's a old question... but I not found a similar answer on another question.*

I was having this issue for months. I found today a solution on my PC (win7 x64):
I run VS2010 with administrator privileges (uac enabled, popup appears and I accept everytime that I run vs 2010) this is because I need a 3rd party addon to work.

It appears that running vs 2010 with admin privileges make it run on another account or something else...

I checked one setting on vs2010 that allowed me to edit and continue now again :)

this option is under:

**Tools/Options/Debugging -> Edit and Continue -> check "Enable while remote debugging or debugging and aplication running under another user account"**

note: vs2010 will show a warning (security related...).. I not sure how dangerous it is... but works

I hope that this solution can help someone.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, someone added a Reference to the Project's output into the Reference list: in Solution Explorer look under [ProjectName]\References for [ProjectName*] and remove it. If the project is relying on code from a copy of itself, you can't 'Edit and Continue'.

In the warning list you'll see **conflicts with imported type** messages if this was the cause of the problem.

Comment: Omg this happened to me. I would never have found this without you. Thanks man you just made my day, I've been beating my head against the wall with this!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this as well. It seems that some stuff of the expressions and lambdas cause this. ;(

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and found this info from the MSDN page ["How to: Use Edit and Continue (C#)"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164926.aspx) :

> Note
>   Edit and Continue is not supported when debugging 64-bit code, the Compact Framework, optimized code, mixed native/managed code, or SQL Server common language runtime (CLR) integration code. If you try to apply code changes in one of these scenarios, the debugger puts up a dialog box explaining that Edit and Continue is not supported.

I think the mix of native/managed code is the problem for me (my project indeed mixes them).