# What would get edit and continue working again?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, edit-and-continue

Visual Studio's edit-and-continue feature stopped working at some point again.

VisualStudio 2010 sp1 professional. I'm writing a dll with **c++ native code**. I run the host 32bit executable from the ide. I have the .pdb beside the .dll. I tried just editing some whitespace to eliminate the possibility that I'm creating scenarios that aren't possible to inject. I hit "apply changes" and this is what I see in the output window.

```
-------- Edit and Continue build started --------

--------------------- Done ----------------------
```

However I see this in a dialog that pops up:

```
Edit and Continue
----------------------------------------
Edits were made which cannot be compiled

Click Edit to fix the code.
Click Stop to stop debugging.
Click Ignore to continue without applying edits
[Edit][Stop][Ignore]
```

Anyone have ideas about how to go about fixing this? The code does compile. Debug breakpoints work. I just want to cut down on the long start-up times this application has to do the testing.

Comment: Do you have this issue for ANY kind of change. In C#, I have seen this behavior for some changes like modifying an anonymous method. Specifically, what change is causing this?

Comment: I can't seem to get any change to work. I just add and delete a character to trigger the system. I've also tried editing an assignment to a local variable.

Comment: Does this happen on x64? Searching on the net yielded this link - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2011/03/08/announcing-visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1.aspx?PageIndex=2. There are references in it that talks about x64 - I am unable to verify since I am on x86.

Comment: I've been on a 64bit host machine for 8 years building for both 32 and 64bit. Neither work. They used to.

Comment: You should also check the answers in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329988/visual-studio-2013-edit-and-continue-not-working

Comment: I no longer have this setup. So I couldn't tell you what helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

If this works for you, you can upvote the original Post by the author of this link (and its answer): [Can't edit and continue when using Visual Studio 2010 on a 64 bit machine, app targets x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795795/cant-edit-and-continue-when-using-visual-studio-2010-on-a-64-bit-machine-app-ta)